# How to get veoh video thumbnail using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, video-thumbnails

I am developing a wordpress plugin VIDEO LIST MANAGER: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/video-list-manager/

I don't know if veoh supports us to get a veoh video thumbnail. I want to add VEOH to my plugin and what i need are: 
1. embed link (yes)
2. thumbnail image (no)

Please help me!

Thanks

Comment: you should show what you've tried. in the mean time, this should help: 
http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/doc.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have the link to the video, e.g. `http://www.veoh.com/watch/abcdef123456` you first need to use the API method [veoh.video.findByPermalink](http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/doc.html?method=veoh.video.findByPermalink) to get the video ID:

```
http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/execute.xml?method=veoh.video.findByPermalink
                                       &permalink=abcdef123456
                                       &apiKey=12345678-1234-...
```

You will get an XML of this structure:

```
<rsp>
  <videoList offset="0" items="1" numItems="1">
    <video videoId="12345" ... >
    ...
```

With that video ID you can then use the API method [veoh.video.getVideoThumbnails](http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/doc.html?method=veoh.video.getVideoThumbnails) to get thumbnails of that video:

```
http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/execute.xml?method=veoh.video.getVideoThumbnails
                                       &videoId=12345
                                       &apiKey=12345678-1234-...
```

You will get an XML of this structure:

```
<rsp>
  <thumbList offset="0" items="33" numItems="10">
    <thumbnail lowResImage="http://....jpg" highResImage="http://....jpg">
    </thumbnail>
    <thumbnail lowResImage="http://....jpg" highResImage="http://....jpg">
    </thumbnail>
    ...
```

The API is really easy to use, for a complete list of methods see the [documentation](http://www.veoh.com/rest/v2/doc.html).

Comment: I can not be qualify to become veoh's partner. So, I can not have API key. :(

Comment: You don't need the API secret for this method... just saying. Still won't help you with your plugin, I guess.

Comment: Thanks, anyway! So I will ignore veoh and find some other video sites :|